# Heatmap plugin crashing/ No longer available for QGIS 2.16?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, heat-map, qgis-2.16

I am a Windows user, quite new to QGIS, and I just updated my QGIS to 2.16 (from 2.12 Lyon). I was previously able to create a heatmap overtop a basemap, but my heatmap plugin now crashes the program whenever I try to add that raster layer - my error message just says the program has stopped working.

[image]

I was hoping to uninstall/reinstall the plugin, but all fields are grayed out when I look at the plugin manager, as seen below:

[image]

- Does anyone know if the heatmap is no longer supported in this version of QGIS, or if there is another step I am missing? As I mentioned, I was previously able to create the heatmap using the plugin without much trouble.
- If it is no longer supported, which version of QGIS would you recommend using? I am uncertain what to download in the list of previous versions of QGIS (ex: **QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.12.2-1-Setup-x86_64.exe** VS **qgis-2.16.2.tar.bz2.md5**).
- Are there recommended alternatives to showing data in the heatmap style over a basemap without the plug in?

Comment: It seems that you are working under windows. I tried a couple of times and I can not reproduce your problem. I have the heatmap option under the raster menu as usual

Comment: I can see the Heatmap option under my raster, but I can't explain the crashing. I have gone back to using QGIS 2.12 and this seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph I'll have to look into that. Nearly all other plugins were not greyed out, which is part of why I was a bit confused, but maybe there was some access issue I was missing.

Comment: @newuser - I think the reason the options are greyed out is because certain plugins are made **core** to QGIS, i.e. they come bundled with the installation. The _Heatmap_ plugin is one of them, another example is _Coordinate Capture_.